# Chrome Extension Published to tester gives 404 not found

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I'd like to publish a Chrome Extension I developed to some test users.

I created a Development account, payed the developer signup fee, uploaded the zip file and I published it to the trusted tester google group of which I am the owner. In the dashboard I can see the app status I expected (Published to tester).

The problem is that if members of that google group click on the extension link, they receive a 404 not found. Pls advise whats wrong here

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: Testers whose email have been added to google group account should be able to access and install the extension using the URL shared with them. Currently they get to see 404 i.e. extension is not available to them

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue just now. 404 when I access the link from a tester's account. The comment from James gave me a thought to try to clean cookies for the chrome store when I am signed in from the testing account. It worked!

1. Go to the link in CWS that you can find in the developer dashboard by clicking the name of your extension.
2. Click lock icon at the url text field.
3. Cookies -> Remove all

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, but in my case with the exact same scenario, it turned out that I was using the wrong URL to see it. This made it for me: `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/<Plugin name with "-" instead of whitespaces>/<Plugin id>`

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It may take several minutes to a couple hours before your Chrome Extension is published and made available.

Your testers have to sign in with an account in your developer dashboard tester accounts.

One weird problem I just came across today was that one tester was logged in with two accounts, her personal account and her work account and only her work account was on the list of tester accounts. Switching to the work account with the dropdown still caused her to see the 404 page. She had to sign out of her personal account before she was able to access the extension chrome store page. (We discovered this issue when we found that she could see the extension page when logging into her work account in Chrome Incognito, but 404 otherwise.)